# How do I "open up" 3rd party libraries' __slots__ -based object instances for attribute assignment?

Tags: python

Let's say I want to assign new attributes to object instances returned by a 3rd party library that returns instances using slots.

(For example, setting some values on SQLAlchemy's RowProxy rows for data that you do not intend to write back to the database.)

Because the instance have `__slots__`, I am going to get an AttributeError or the like.  That's expected, but what's a workaround?

## Desired behavior/constraints

1. Consider the 3rd party library is a black box, can't change its return types.
2. Preserve as much of the original instances' behavior as possible (methods, properties, etc...).
3. Assigning to attributes in the slots should affect the original instance's attributes.

This is what I came up with, Proxy2 works, but is there something more elegant/simpler?  What are the risks of it breaking?  Will it work on Python 3 (I am on 2.7, but plan to upgrade to 3.x eventually).

```
class Slotted(object):
    __slots__ = ("a","b")

    def hello(self):
        print("hello %s" % (self.a))

    def __init__(self, a="1", b="2"):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

def test_it(f):

    fname = f.__name__

    print("\n\ntest_it(%s)" % (fname))

    instances = [Slotted(a=11), Slotted()]
    try:
        li_test = [f(obj) for obj in instances]
    except Exception, e:
        print("%s.failure at instance modification:%s" % (fname, str(e)[0:100]))
        return

    for cntr, tgt in enumerate(li_test):
        try:
            tgt.cntr = cntr
            print("tgt.cntr:%s" % (tgt.cntr))
            #do I still have my function?
            tgt.hello()
            tgt.a = 100
        except Exception, e:
            print("%s.failure:%s" % (fname, str(e)[0:100]))
            return

    #test that an attribute assignment to the slots actually went there...
    for ori in instances:
        try:
            assert ori.a == 100
        except AssertionError:
            print("%s.failure:original instance should have its slot-based attribute set to 100, but is still %s" % (fname, ori.a))
            break

    print "%s.success" % (fname)

class Proxy2(object):
    """this works, can it be improved on?"""

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.__dict__["_obj"] = obj

    def __setattr__(self, attrname, value):
        if attrname in self._obj.__slots__:
            setattr(self._obj, attrname, value)
        else:
            self.__dict__[attrname] = value

    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        try:
            return getattr(self._obj, attrname)
        except AttributeError:
            raise

#subclass Slotted
class Opener(Slotted):
    """fails w Slotted' object layout differs from 'Opener'"""
    pass

class Opener2(Slotted):
    """fails w Slotted' object layout differs from 'Opener2'"""
    __slots__ = Slotted.__slots__ + ("__dict__",)

#functions to modify the original instances
def proxy_instances(obj):
    #this works
    return Proxy2(obj)

def do_nothing(obj):
    #fails, normal, this is the baseline slots behavior
    return obj

def modify_class(obj):
    #change the instance's class to a subclass that has a __dict__
    obj.__class__ = Opener

def modify_class2(obj):
    #change the instance's class to a subclass to add __dict__ to the __slots__
    obj.__class__ = Opener2

for func in [do_nothing, modify_class, modify_class2, proxy_instances]:
    test_it(func)
```

output:

```
test_it(do_nothing)
do_nothing.failure:'Slotted' object has no attribute 'cntr'


test_it(modify_class)
modify_class.failure at instance modification:__class__ assignment: 'Slotted' object layout differs from 'Opener'


test_it(modify_class2)
modify_class2.failure at instance modification:__class__ assignment: 'Slotted' object layout differs from 'Opener2'


test_it(proxy_instances)
tgt.cntr:0
hello 11
tgt.cntr:1
hello 1
proxy_instances.success
```

Answer (score 2):

I would take the result returned from the 3rd party library, and store it in my own container object of some sort (eg class or dictionary) along with the other data I want to store.

This approach would be more explicit, straight-forward, comprehensible, less tricky. Since it's not monkey-patching 3rd party data in a tricky way, it's more likely to avoid mysterious bugs.

Comment: But that's kind of what I am doing with the Proxy already, isn't it?  Not being sarcastic, just checking what you mean by that.  I am just trying to figure out what the usual approach is with this type of problem.

Comment: The `Proxy` is an interesting idea. Two comments: (1) I'd be unsure in usage whether attribute gets/sets are going to the `Proxy` object or the object contained within it. (2) It looks as though it only works with an object using `__slots__`, which is an implementation detail of the 3rd party library.